# Что не так с решением задачи?

Tags: python

Написать функцию is_year_leap, принимающую 1 аргумент — год, и возвращающую True, если год високосный, и False иначе.

```
def is_year_leap(year):
    year = int(input("Введите год: "))
    if year % 4 != 0 or (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: А зачем в функции запрашивать год, если он уже передаётся туда аргументом?

Answer (score 3):

Не так - строчка `year = int(input("Введите год: "))`. Не нужно спрашивать год, если он уже передаётся в функцию аргументом.

И условие неправильное, конечно же.

Answer (score 0):

Неправильное условие. На самом деле - високосный год - это год, номер которого (кратен 4, но не кратен 100) или (кратен 400). (Расставил скобки для удобства понимания).

Так же можно избавить от `else`, который идёт после ветки, содержащей `return`. Например:

```
if cond:
    return True
else
    return False
```

можно упростить в:

```
if cond:
    return True
return False
```

Однако и тут можно сделать проще. Заметьте, что возвращаемое значение всегда равно переменной `cond`. Тогда отрывок выше превратится в:

```
return cond
```

А ваш код преобразуется в:

```
def is_year_leap(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0
```

Наконец добавлю, что в вашем коде скобки в условии лишние. Согласно приоритету сначала вычисляется `x and y` а потом `z or t`